# Трансформация Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Коллеги, необходимо привести DataFrame к следующему виду:

[image: эталонная таблица]

Сейчас таблица имеет следующий вид:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Year': ['1999-01-31','2000-01-31','2001-01-31','2002-01-31','2003-01-31'],
                       'Value': ['13','10','12','14','16']})
```

Нужно отбросить число дня, число месяца можно так и оставить числом. Ранее задавал подобный вопрос тут:[Преобразование DataFrame](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1207284/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-dataframe)
Сейчас возникла необходимость обратного преобразования.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваш датасет непоказателен. я его немного расширил:

```
import pandas as pd
import calendar
df = pd.DataFrame({'Year': ['1999-01-31','2000-01-31','2001-01-31','2002-01-31','2003-01-31', '1999-02-31','2000-02-31','2001-02-31','2002-02-31','2003-02-31'],
                   'Value': ['13','10','12','14','16', '23','20','22','24','26']})
```

Дальше просто:

```
df[["Year", "Month"]] = df["Year"].str.split("-", n=1, expand=True)
res = df.pivot(index="Year", columns="Month", values="Value")
res.columns = [calendar.month_abbr[int(x.split("-")[0])] for x in res.columns]
```

res:

```
     Jan Feb
Year        
1999  13  23
2000  10  20
2001  12  22
2002  14  24
2003  16  26
```